# Consulta Compuesta Realtime Database Android

Tags: android, firebase

A ver si me pueden ayudar para ver como puedo hacer una consulta compuesta en firebase.Intento hacer una busqueda de concepto y dni pero al parecer me da fallos de que no puedo combinar varios orderBy.Este es mi intento de consulta:

```
Query consulta = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(nodos.nodoControl).orderByChild(nodos.nodoUsuarios_dni).equalTo(dni).orderByChild(nodos.nodoControl_concepto).equalTo(concepto);
```

Luego eso lo meto en un listener.

```
consulta.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    datos.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Control c = snapshot.getValue(Control.class);
                        datos.add(c);
                    }
                }
                listaConcepto.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

Y salta el siguiente error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.cuentas, PID: 23149
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You can't combine multiple orderBy calls!
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.validateNoOrderByCall(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:136)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.orderByChild(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:638)
        at com.example.cuentas.consultaConcepto.rellenarLista(consultaConcepto.java:58)
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Ya encontre la solucion.

Comment: Hola manu, si encontraste la solucion estaria genial que la publiques como respuesta debajo, asi otros usuarios con el mismo problema pueden obtener la solucion, un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido arreglarlo de esta manera,no se si es "código limpio" por así decirlo pero me hace lo que necesito.

```
private void rellenarLista(final String concepto) {
        Query consulta = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(nodos.nodoControl).orderByChild(nodos.nodoUsuarios_dni).equalTo(dni);
        consulta.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    datos.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Control c = snapshot.getValue(Control.class);
                        if (c.getConcepto().equalsIgnoreCase(concepto)) {
                            datos.add(c);
                        }
                    }
                }
                listaConcepto.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

Recojo todos los datos que tenga con el dni y una vez tengo todos los datos los recorro haciendo uso de un objeto el cual le digo que si el objeto del datasnapshot en cuestión es igual al concepto que busco me lo añada a un ArrayList. Realmente no se si esta bien implementado desde el punto de vista de una buena programación pero obtener obtengo los datos que necesito